# How to label filters that filter on overlapping date ranges

Tags: filter, labels, datetimepicker

I am looking for the appropropriate labeling for filters that search an event that is active within the provided date range.

```
Filters:
Ends after <date input>
Starts before <date input>

Result:
+-----+------+---------+
| ... | From | Through |
+-----+------+---------+
```

The (pseudocode) implementation of these filters is as follows:

```
endsAfter.HasValue && endsAfter <= Through
startsBefore.HasValue && startsBefore >= From
```

I have labeled them `Ends after` and `Starts before` for now but I'm wondering if there are better alternatives.

Comment: Could you explain more what you application is doing?

Comment: The purpose of this screen is to find Group Reservations for a hotel. These filters are used to see which groups are in-house during the selected time period.

Comment: I think you already gave some alternatives for you: 1. Time period, 2. Date range 3. Start/Beginning - End. I am a little bit confused why you want to say "Starts before" and not "Starts", "Ends after" and not "Ends". Is it about flexibility?

Comment: I would interpret "Starts" as the exact date that the event starts

Answer (score 1):

The labels `Ends after` and `Starts before` make sense for you as the developer. You need to search for events that:

1. End after the first date in the date range
2. Start before the last date in the date range

The users just wants to see what events are active during a number of days (weeks / whatever). I would suggest:

> Show events that are active between `[start-date-input]` and `[end-date-input]`

Or at least something in the same line.
You could also try using a date range selector.

Good luck.

Comment: This way of displaying it is not working for me:
• Either date is optional, this representation doesn't show that.
• The example is simplified, this page has over dozen+ filters
• Doesn't need to be this verbose, all users are trained staff

Comment: Then, your current solution might be best. Not many weeks ago I tried changing similar labels in the enterprise application the company I work at build. Only to meet resistance by the user who were trained staff as well.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool This is most of the times the case. The trained staff are afraid of the change, without realizing that it might be better for them.